# When does a slash indicate the start of a regex?

Tags: javascript, syntax

When exactly does a slash (`/`) indicate the start of a regular expression?

I'm trying to write a parser for a javascript sandbox, but I'm having trouble figuring out wether a given `/` is an operator or the start of a regular expression.

Comment: When it's a regex literal. But I'm not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECMAScript Language Specification - ECMA-262 Edition 5.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7)

Comment: @VLAZ What exactly do you mean by regex literal? If I'm not mistaken, `/f/g` should be a valid regex literal, but when I add a letter before it, it does get treated as division (for example `e/f/g`)